# Is there a way club two Linux command together in system() function in C?

Tags: c, systems-programming

I wanted to execute *who* command and *cut* out the needed info like `who | cut -d " " -f 1,21,23` but by using the system() function in c.

I tried doing `system("who | cut -d " " -f 1,21,23")` which did not work.

**The code:**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define ErrorBC -69
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    if(argc < 2){
        printf("No arguments passed\n");
        return -69;
    }
    else{
        int i=0;
        for(i=1;i<argc;i++){
        if((strcmp("kernel",argv[i]))==0){
            system("uname -s -r");
        }
        else if(((strcmp("ulog",argv[i]))==0)){
                system("who | cut -d " " -f 1,21,23");
        }
        else{
            printf("%s is not a valid options\n",argv[i]);
        }
    }
    }
}
```

**The output:**

```
c99 test.c
/usr/sahil: ./a.out ulog
Usage: cut {-b <list> [-n] | -c <list> | -f <list> [-d <char>] [-s]} file ...
```

Comment: That's the double quotes after `-d` interfering leading to string literal concatenation (which then leads to `cut` seeing no value against the `-d` parameter and failing). Escape the quotes after `-d`.

Comment: Or replace the `" "` with `' '`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `"who | cut -d " " -f 1,21,23"` you have *two* strings: `"who | cut -d "` and `" -f 1,21,23"`. They are concatenated to `"who | cut -d -f 1,21,23"`.

To include double-quotes inside C strings you need to *escape* them with the backslash: `"who | cut -d \" \" -f 1,21,23"`.